# decimal to binary with bitwise operators

Tags: c

hi im trying to write program in c that Take a decimal number as an input and display its equivalent binary number using bitwise operations.output is displayed in 32 bits

```
#include <stdio.h>
int desimal2binary (int desimal){
    int binary = 0 ; 
    int num_binary;
    int i = 0 ;

    while (desimal>0)
    {
        binary |= ((desimal&1)<<i);
        desimal>>= 1 ;
        i++;
    }
    return binary ;
    
}

int main(){
    int num_desimal , num_binary ;
    scanf("%d",&num_desimal);
    num_binary = desimal2binary(num_desimal);
    printf("%d",num_binary);

}
```

`

input : 59
output : 00000000000000000000000000111011
but program output is 59 !

Comment: The function printf is unable to output a number in the binary format. Moreover your function does not make sense because numbers are already stored in the binary format. Pay attention to that just to output a number in the binary format there is no need to convert it to another objec. Otherwise you could convert a number in a string.

Comment: If you observe `binary` and `desimal` during your loop (either via debugger or by lots of printing debug messages, you will see that what you are doing is an   elaborate way of creating bit by bit a copy of the input. A bit by bit identical copy. I am not surprised that the output is identical to the input.

Comment: Instead of manipulating bits you can multiply multiples of 10. Ex 111011 is one hundred eleven thousand eleven.

Comment: Or use a string to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are correct, what you seem to be doing is building a binary copy of the original input integer. It seems the task is to output the integer in binary notation. You could simply build a string with 0s and 1s based on bit setting in num_desmal:

```
void desimal2binary(int desimal, char *pbuf)
    {
    for (unsigned i = 1 << ((sizeof(i) * 8) - 1); i; i >>= 1)
        *pbuf++ = (i & desimal) ? '1' : '0';
    *pbuf = '\0';
    }
```